# Tool to create video-best ofs and manage video snippets centrally

Tags: video, video-editing

I need a tool, preferrably OSS and free, to create best ofs from long twitch and youtube streams and manage the video snippets at a central place. Something like:

- import function for videos, such as a 3hour livestream local copy (original video)
- marking several sections (snippets) in that original video for a best of, including adding tags, descriptions
- copying snippets from several long videos and combining them into a new shorter video (best of)
- additional video editing options, such as subtitles, transitions between snippets, basic effects
- export of the best of video in most common video formats (mpeg, avi)
  nice to have: adding a configurable watermark in the snippet that can contain information from the original video, in order to comply with copyright. Copyright often requires to make a reference to the source of the snippet.

This should help to avoid having a large amount of local video snippets and managing them as individual video files. It would be better to cut and recombine them from the original video. The tool should therefore act as an overlay for pulling the snippets out of these large videos and to easily create best ofs, fail videos, etc.